# jdbctemplate - queryForList - Passing a date?

Tags: java, spring, jdbc

I'm writing a small spring application which has jdbc functionality in the context of the following code...

I have the following java to set up an SQL query string :

```
    String sql =
            "SELECT " +
                    "    a.Id, " +
                    "    a.USER_ID ", " +
                    "    a.LAST_UPDATED " +
                    "from " +
                    "    Schema.AwesomeTable a " +
                    "where " +
                    "    a.LAST_UPDATED >= ?";
```

and I am trying to use a date object (let's just imagine I am using the current date for the sake of this question remaining brief) :

```
Date myDate = new Date(); // This is a java.util.Date
```

and I am calling the query like this :

```
List<Map<String, Object>> rows = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(sql, new Object[]{myDate});
```

When I run this - I get this error :

```
2019-04-08 23:17:58 - Setting SQL statement parameter value: column index 1, parameter value [Tue Apr 08 23:17:58 CDT 2019], value class [java.util.Date], SQL type unknown
```

I could really use some help - I have googled around everywhere, and I've found SOME information, but I haven't seen anything that I seem to be able to grasp.

Comment: Try by wrapping that in java.sql.Date.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap your parameter in `java.sql.Date` or use:

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.time.LocalDate;

LocalDate dateTime = // some date here
Date startDate = Date.from(dateTime.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
```

Comment: Thanks, but when I do this it actually just crashes out and says invalid column type, unfortunately :(

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly use `myDate` variable of type `java.util.Date` in your sql query

```
Date myDate = new Date(); // This is a java.util.Date
```

you have to convert it to `java.sql.Date` type which you can do as follows:

```
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(myDate.getTime());
```

after which you can call the query like:

```
List<Map<String, Object>> rows = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(sql,sqlDate);
```

which will work as expected.

Comment: See, I 100% thought that was how it might work, but when I do that I still get the same error - except with the type changed as follows : Setting SQL statement parameter value: column index 1, parameter value [2019-04-09], value class [java.sql.Date], SQL type unknown

The column type is "Date", and this is an oracle db

Comment: oracle by default accepts date in the following format :                                      insert into table
(date_column)
values
('31-oct-02');

Comment: you can use   Oracle's to_date function  : `insert into table
(date_column)
values
(to_date('023110', 'YYDDMM'));` Better convert date to the*** oracles default format ***  than using to_date

Answer (score 0):

**LocalDate can be pass as String in prepard statement directly **

```
jdbcTemplate.query(selectSqlQuery,
                    ps -> {
                        ps.setString(1, searchDate.toString());
                    }, new RowMapperForOutput());
```

Query:

select * from table1 where date(date_column)= ?;